# API load testing from different servers with unique AUTH_TOKEN

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, stress-testing

I want to test an API endpoint which requires AUTH header and I want to run them from different servers, so they'll hit different threads. However, I don't know how to do this because AUTH tokens should be different on each of this test servers. Is there a way to organize it using JMeter with redline13 specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameterize your server and Auth_Token with a cvs file and upload the JMX and csv file to Redline13 to run the load test

1. Create a csv file and map IP address with Auth Token.
   [image]
   2.Add a header config manager to your http request , you can use `${variablename}` to replace ip and authtoken as shown below

[image]
[image]

Result: 
[image]

For more info on running a JMeter test please read this [article](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2017/02/jmeter/)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an use case for [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), if you have a CSV file which looks like:

```
ip,token
10.20.30.40,foo
10.10.99.4,bar
.etc
```

1. Add CSV Data Set Config to your Test Plan and provide your CSV file name there

   [image: JMeter CSV Data Set]
2. In [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler put `${ip}` into "Server Name or IP" field

   [image: JMeter configure IP from CSV]
3. Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) as a child of your HTTP Request sampler and configure it to send `AUTH` header with the value of `${token}`

   [image: JMeter Header Manager]
4. That's it, each JMeter thread (virtual user) will read the next line of the CSV file and therefore request will go to the specified server with the specified header.

   [image: JMeter Parameterize IP and header with CSV]